# Flutter can't connect to SocketIO

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I'm a newbie in Flutter.

I want to build an application that triggers an alarm when event is incoming. so I tried using SocketIO as a backend but I stuck with this error in Flutter's console.

I build floatingActionButton for sending message test. When the button is pressed from the first phone, another phone should show 'Alert' in the debug console. But it didn't show any.

This is the error when the page is showing.

```
I/flutter ( 3536): CREATING NEW SOCKET: http://localhost:8080/alert
I/flutter ( 3536): Created
I/flutter ( 3536): Initialized
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: FlutterSocketIoPlugin( 3536): onMethodCall: socketInit - domain: http://localhost:8080 - with namespace: /alert
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: TOTAL SOCKETS: ( 3536): 0
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: TOTAL SOCKETS: ( 3536): 0
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: added SocketIO( 3536): http://localhost:8080/alert
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 3536): connecting...null
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: FlutterSocketIoPlugin( 3536): onMethodCall: socketSubcribes - domain: http://localhost:8080 - with namespace: /alert
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: FlutterSocketIoPlugin( 3536): socketData: {"alert_user":"FunctionId@624955072"}
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: TOTAL SOCKETS: ( 3536): 1
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 3536): --- subscribes ---{"alert_user":"FunctionId@624955072"}
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: subscribe( 3536): channel: alert_user - with callback: FunctionId@624955072
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: socketInfo( 3536): SUBSCRIBES SIZES: NULL or EMPTY
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: socketInfo( 3536): SUBSCRIBES SIZES: 1
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: socketInfo( 3536): CHANNEL: alert_user with TOTAL LISTENERS: 1
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: FlutterSocketIoPlugin( 3536): onMethodCall: socketConnect - domain: http://localhost:8080 - with namespace: /alert
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: TOTAL SOCKETS: ( 3536): 1
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 3536): connecting socket: http://localhost:8080/alert
W/sinessDetectio( 3536): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/sinessDetectio( 3536): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/sinessDetectio( 3536): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/sinessDetectio( 3536): Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/sinessDetectio( 3536): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 3536): connect_error: [{"cause":{"detailMessage":"CLEARTEXT communication to localhost not permitted by network security policy","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"websocket error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]}]
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 3536): reconnect_attempt: [1]
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 3536): reconnecting: [1]
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 3536): connect_error: [{"cause":{"detailMessage":"CLEARTEXT communication to localhost not permitted by network security policy","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"websocket error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]}]
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 3536): reconnect_error: [{"cause":{"cause":{"detailMessage":"CLEARTEXT communication to localhost not permitted by network security policy","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"websocket error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"Connection error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]}]
```

It continues to give me this error all the time.

Console from pressing floatingActionButton in the first phone.

```
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: FlutterSocketIoPlugin( 5570): onMethodCall: socketSendMessage - domain: http://localhost:8080 - with namespace: /alert
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: TOTAL SOCKETS: ( 5570): 1
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 5570): socket id: http://localhost:8080/alert is connected: false
```

This is my server code

```
const app = require("express")();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

server.listen(PORT);
console.log("Server is Running on Port " + PORT);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Node Server is running. Yay!!");
});

const alert = io.of("/alert");

alert.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id, "joined");

  socket.on("alert_detect", (data) => {
    alert.emit("alert_user", data);
  });
});
```

and this is my Flutter code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_socket_io/flutter_socket_io.dart';
import 'package:flutter_socket_io/socket_io_manager.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/main-screen';
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  SocketIO socketIO;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initSocketIO();
    super.initState();
  }

  _initSocketIO() {
    socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO(
      'http://localhost:8080',
      '/alert',
    );
    print('Created');
    socketIO.init();
    print('Initialized');
    socketIO.subscribe('alert_user', _socketAlert);
    socketIO.connect();
  }

  _socketAlert() {
    print('Alert');
  }

  void _sendMessage(msg) async {
    if (socketIO != null) {
      String jsonData = '{msg: msg,id: 1}';
      socketIO.sendMessage("alert_detect", jsonData);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: <My body>,
      // This is sending test
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: Icon(Icons.alarm),
        onPressed: () {
          _sendMessage('Hi');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Do I misunderstand something?
Thank you. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost`

```
_initSocketIO() {
    socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO(
      'http://10.0.2.2:8080',
      '/alert',
    );
    print('Created');
    socketIO.init();
    print('Initialized');
    socketIO.subscribe('alert_user', _socketAlert);
    socketIO.connect();
  }
```

for more information you can check https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. Now, It is working properly.